# React And Python app development and delpoying on Azure

Tags: python-3.x, reactjs, azure, react-native

Actually i am working on a project, But know i am not able to setup and configure it with azure that what all technologies i should use, The project is that:-
from the react front end user will enter the data in inputs from that will be stored in azure DB and at a **particular time** that data should be fetched by the python prog and process the data and display the output on React front end

Answer (score 0):

Host your react and python app in windows azure as 'WEB APPS'. 
If you are using mysql as DB use Azure mysql as database service.

Please watch this azure YT tutorial to get an idea of azure.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tDuruX7XSac

Comment: sir be specific and tell me through what process i should work

Comment: Please go through the reference video. It will teach you with practical examples in each top. since azure is the vast area. I prefer watching tutorial videos might helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Using Azure as a deployment service and database service seems slightly overambitious but if you wanted a step by step breakdown:

1. configure Python to query Azure DB:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-python

2. configure your React app to make asynchronous requests to your Python API (locally).
3. deploy both to Azure
4. re-configure your deployed React web application to connect with your deployed Python API.